# Determine all complex numbers for which: Arg(z^5 ) = π/2 an |z| = 2.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I came across this question on a complex analysis course, and my idea of the solution starts with Arg(z^5)=Arg(z*z*z*z*z)=Arg(z+z+z+z+z)=π/2 =>Arg(z)=π/10. But i cant describe the |z|=2.

Answer (score 2):

If $z = re^{i\theta}$ then $z^5 = r^5 e^{5i\theta}$.

$r$ is already given as $|2|$, so the problem reduces to finding all possible values of $\theta$, within a modulus of $(2\pi)$, such that

$$5\theta \equiv (\pi/2) \pmod{2\pi}.$$

One easy approach is to presume that $(5 \theta)$ must be an element in

$$\{(\pi/2), (2\pi + \pi/2), (4\pi + \pi/2), (6\pi + \pi/2), (8\pi + \pi/2)\}.$$

This results in [within a modulus of $(2\pi)$],

$$\pi \in \{(\pi/10), (\pi/2), (9\pi/10), (13\pi/10), (17\pi/10)\}.$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer i do apreciate it. The same formula applies when i have a question like 'describe the complex numbers z which arg(z^6)=arg(z^2)? but with the only diffirence i put θ=0?

Comment: @ergolavos $\text{arg}(z^6) ~=~ \text{arg}(z^2) \iff ~\text{arg}(z^4) \equiv 0\pmod{2\pi}.~~$ Here, you can let $\theta = \text{arg}(z) \implies 4\theta = \text{arg}(z^4).$  Then, you assume that $4(\theta) \in \{0, 2\pi, 4\pi, 6\pi\}~$ and then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$, that means $|z|=\rho$ and $\arg(z)=\theta$. Then $\rho=2$, and
$$\arg(z^5)=\arg(\rho^5e^{i 5\theta})=5\theta=2k\pi+\dfrac{\pi}2, \quad k=0,1,2,\dots$$
then
$$\theta=\dfrac25k\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{10}=\dfrac1{10}\pi,\dfrac12\pi,\dfrac{9}{10}\pi,\dfrac{13}{10}\pi,\dfrac{17}{10}\pi.$$